# Popup item loses opaquness

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a weird problem with `Popup` QML component from QtQuick2 , when I do `open()` it, it shows with transparent background , and it should be opaque.

This is how I call the `Popup` component from the `main.qml` file :

```
NewUser {
    id: new_user_form
}
```

This is the component's source:

```
// File: NewUser.qml
Popup {
    id: new_user_popup
    modal: true
    focus: true
    x: 10
    y: 10
    width: 300
    height: 200


    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "red"
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

[image: Transparent Popup]

Now, I can fix this error by moving the source of the `NewUser.qml` into `main.qml` and everything looks fine now:

This is the now 'fixed' `main.qml`:

```
Popup {
    id: new_user_form
    modal: true
    focus: true
    x: 10
    y: 10
    width: 300
    height: 200
}
```

See, the popup is completely **OPAQUE**:

[image]

So, why if I move the source code of the component into a separate file from `main.qml` it loses the opaquness ? My main.qml has a lot of other stuff, but I believe it is not related to the popup, also the ID is unique. I hope this is not some issue with QT 5.8 RC (which I am using for development) , it is not yet official but soon it will be.

**EDIT:**

I believe I found a bug. The bug is reproducible with Qt 5.8 and Qt 5.7

To reproduce, create a project with the following files:

Main file:

```
//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    NewUser {
        id: new_user_form
    }
    Button {
        text: "open popup"
        onClicked:  {
            new_user_form.open()
        }
    }
}
```

The component file (NewUser.qml)

```
//File: NewUser.qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
import QtQuick.Templates 2.0

Popup {
    id: new_user_popup
    modal: true
    focus: true
    x: 10; y:10;
    height: 200; width: 300;

    Button {
        text: "Test button"
    }
}


//File: qtquickcontrols2.conf
; This file can be edited to change the style of the application
; See Styling Qt Quick Controls 2 in the documentation for details:
; http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html

[Controls]
Style=Material

[Universal]
Theme=Light
;Accent=Steel

[Material]
Theme=Light
;Accent=BlueGrey
;Primary=BlueGray



//File: main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

That does the bug do? If you click on the button "open popup" you will see a dimmed screen but no popup at all.

Comment: I also made an example of main.qml containing only minimal ApplicationWindow component and included the code to open the Popup component (which goes in a separate .qml file) and the background (of the Popup) is, in fact opaque, as it should be. So it is _my_ main.qml that messes everything, but I don't have any errors in it. And the other stuff is completely unrelated, so I have no clues on why is this happening.

Comment: Another problem I have found, is that if I add a `Button {}` to the _bad_ (transparent) Popup component, it does not show. But when I copy the code to main.qml , the button shows perfectly well.

Comment: As you said, the problem should be in your `main.qml`. I also write an example and it works well. Did you try with `opacity: 1.0` in your popup?

Comment: @Tarod , _My_ main.qml is fine. The problem is in Qt. I tried 5.7 and 5.8, with freshly created project, and this example `FAILs`! I do not understand how it can work `OK` for you. Did you copy all the files as is?

Comment: I was referring to the original question, not the bug. [Code here](https://gist.github.com/ftena/0c7df30aec6e750754b419fc5f11f636).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug. See, you are not using a namespace for the templates import.

```
import QtQuick.Templates 2.0 as T
```

For the sake of clarity, there is a one-to-one mapping between the types provided by the `QtQuick.Templates` and `QtQuick.Controls` imports. For every type available in the `QtQuick.Controls` import, a non-visual template type by the same name exists in the `QtQuick.Templates` import. It is recommended to use a namespace for the templates import to avoid overlap with the types provided by the `QtQuick.Controls` import.

Comment: Thanks! that was it. I wonder , why Qt docs of (for example) ButtonGroup component don't say anything that it is a template. I can use ButtonGroup only as `T.ButtonGroup` in my .qml documents, not `ButtonGroup` itself. Because otherwise QtCreator says "the component is not recognized"